# %(percentage) symbol cannot be displayed when getting the value from textbox and display it in textarea in jsp page through AJAX using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

In my jsp page,

```
<form id="indexForm" name="indexForm" action="LoginAction" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="fname" class="fontStyle">First Name :</td>
        <td id="fvalue"><input type="text" id="firstname"
            name="firstname" /></td>
        <td id="lname" class="fontStyle">Last Name :</td>
        <td id="lvalue"><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" /></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <center><!-- <input type="button" value="End Chat" onclick="getValues()" /> -->
        <a id="button" href="javascript:getValues();">Start chat</a></center>
        </td>
        <td>
        <center><!-- <input type="button" value="End Chat" /> --> <a
            id="button" href="javascript:logout();">Stop chat</a></center>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</table>

</form>

</div>
<div style="display: none;" id="div">
<div><textarea id="textarea" rows="10"></textarea></div>
<div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="msg" class="fontStyle">message :</td>
        <td id="msgvalue"><input size="40" type="text" id="message" /></td>
        <td style="width: 5%;"></td>
        <td><!-- <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendMessage()" /> -->
        <a id="button3" href="javascript:sendMessage();">Send</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript,

```
var message ;
var textarea ;

function sendMessage(){


    message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");


    try
    {
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            //alert("Status : "+xmlhttp.status+"\nreadyState : "+xmlhttp.readyState);
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                var checkMsg = encodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
                if(checkMsg != "null" && checkMsg != null){
                    //document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML +=  checkMsg;
                    if(textarea.value == "")
                        textarea.value = checkMsg;
                    else
                        textarea.value += "\n"+ checkMsg  ;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","SendMessageAction?message="+encodeURIComponent(message)+"&sid"+Math.random(),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.description);
    }
}
```

In my servlet ,

```
package com.tps.flexchat.action;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.FlexChatProtocol;
import com.tps.flexchat.Request.SendMessage;
import com.tps.flexchat.info.ApplicationInfo;
import com.tps.flexchat.info.CustomerInfo;

public class SendMessageAction extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String msg;
    private String seckey;
    private String uid;
    private String sessionId;
    private int counter;
    private FlexChatProtocol protocol = null; 
    private SendMessage message;


    public SendMessageAction() {
    super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        msg = request.getParameter("message");
        seckey = request.getParameter("securekey");
        uid = request.getParameter("userId");
        sessionId = request.getParameter("sessionId");
        //counter =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("counter"));
        counter = 1;
        protocol = ApplicationInfo.flexProtocol;

        message = new SendMessage();
        message.send(msg, seckey, uid, sessionId, counter, protocol);

        CustomerInfo customer = ApplicationInfo.customerDetails.get(uid);

        out.print(customer.getMessage());

    }

}
```

sessionId,userId,secureKey can de generated by genesys and working fine..Having problem with msg only...

In java class,

```
package com.tps.flexchat.Request;

import com.genesyslab.platform.commons.protocol.ChannelState;
import com.genesyslab.platform.commons.protocol.Message;
import com.genesyslab.platform.commons.protocol.ProtocolException;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.FlexChatProtocol;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.EventInfo;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.MessageText;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.TreatAs;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.UserType;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.events.EventStatus;
import com.genesyslab.platform.webmedia.protocol.flexchat.requests.RequestRefresh;
import com.tps.flexchat.info.ApplicationInfo;
import com.tps.flexchat.info.CustomerInfo;


public class SendMessage {
    int i = 0;
    public void send(String msg,String seckey, String uid, String sessionId, int counter, FlexChatProtocol protocol){
            CustomerInfo customer = ApplicationInfo.customerDetails.get(uid);
            RequestRefresh refresh = RequestRefresh.create();
            refresh.setMessageText(MessageText.create(null, TreatAs.NORMAL, msg));
            refresh.setFromPosition(customer.getFromPosition()+1);
            refresh.setSecureKey(seckey);
            refresh.setUserId(uid);

            try {
                if(protocol.getState() == ChannelState.Opened){
                    Message resp = protocol.request(refresh);
                    if(resp != null){
                        EventStatus status = (EventStatus)resp;
                        if(status.messageId() == EventStatus.ID){
                            String userId = status.getUserId();

                            if(status.getFlexTranscript() != null && status.getFlexTranscript().getEventInfoList() != null){
                                EventInfo info = (EventInfo) status.getFlexTranscript().getEventInfoList().getLast();

                                    if(customer != null){
                                        customer.setFromPosition(status.getFlexTranscript().getLastPosition());
                                        customer.addMessage(info.getText());
                                    }

                            }


                        }
                    }
                    //System.out.println(msg+";"+seckey+";"+uid+";"+sessionId+";"+counter);
                }else{
                    protocol.open();
                }
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

When I will type any special character in the text field and when pressed the send button , it will call the `sendMessage()` in JavaScript and  displayed the values in the textarea except the % symbol .

All the special character are working except the `%` symbol.

How do I display the `%` symbol?

Comment: post your code for handling SendMessageAction

Comment: Thanks XIAOYI ... I got the solution because of you... Thanks for supporting me..

Comment: although I don't know how you fix it, or what the exact problem is, congratulation. please vote up for the answers that helped you (and mark the one you think is the answer or answer the question yourself to close the question.)

Comment: Now I need to logout my application when I closed the browser window..How can I do this XIAOYI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First never use `escape()`, use `encodeURIComponent()` instead. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for detail.

```
message = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("message").value);
```

Second set the value in the `<textarea>` with `.value` instead of `.innerText`.

```
textarea.value = textarea.value ? textarea.value + '\n' + checkMsg : checkMsg;
```

Third you need to setup `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in requestHeader when make a `POST` request. And send your payload with `xhr.send(data)` instead of passing it with query string.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "SendMessageAction?sid="+Math.random(), true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("message=" + message);
```

All adds up, assuming your response is plain (that is not encoded in url encoding, *it's unnecessary!*)

```
var messageEl = document.getElementById("message");
var textareaEl = document.getElementById("textarea");

function sendMessage(){

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(evt) {
        var checkMsg = xhr.responseText;
        if (textareaEl.value)
            textareaEl.value += '\n';
        textareaEl.value += checkMsg;
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(evt) {
        // handle the error.
    };
    xhr.open('POST', "SendMessageAction?sid="+Math.random(), true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("message=" + encodeURIComponent(messageEL.value));
}
```

And your problems should solve themselves.

Comment: Thanks but now I having problem with the % symbol to display it in the text area..

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're already escaping the messages, but it looks like you also need to URL -encode and then -decode the messages. A + symbol is used in URLs to represent a space, so any actual + symbols will just be removed unless you encode them (to '%2B').

On the Javascript side you can use `encodeURIComponent()` and `decodeURIComponent()`, and on the Java side use `URLDecoder` and `URLEncoder`.

In your Javascript add something like...

```
var checkMsg = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
...

xmlhttp.open("POST","SendMessageAction?message=" + encodeURIComponent(message)  +"&sid"+Math.random(),true);
```

...and in the Java code that send/receives the messages...

```
String inMessage = URLDecoder.decode(rawMessage, "UTF-8");
...
return URLEncoder.encoder(outMessage, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,    It worked in and + symbol displayed in client side Chatting but didn't shows the + symbol in Agent(server) side.. I am doing the chat application..Please help me...

Comment: There is no need to send a encoded result to client! This is very wrong behavior.

Comment: Thanks but now I having problem with the % symbol to display it in the text area..

Comment: Thanks XIAOYI ... I got the solution because of you... Thanks for supporting me..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is,

I used the encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent() instead of escape() , when sending the values to the servlet using AJAX.

My Script was like this,

```
var checkMsg = decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.responseText.toString());
...

xmlhttp.open("POST","SendMessageAction?message=" + encodeURIComponent(message)
```

Thanks for all who supported me  ....